# How much money is needed to get an investment bank account?

Tags: banking, bank-account, investment-income

I heard somewhere that to open a bank account in the Lazard-Rothschild bank, you need to have 2 million euros. Is that true? More generally, I would like to know what is the minimal amount of money necessary to open an investment bank account.

Comment: Are you referring to exclusive investment banks for the ultra-rich?

Comment: I imagine it varies from bank to bank. You'd have to contact the bank(s) you're interested in to find out.

Comment: Account? Investment bank?

Comment: Since we've had an answer about the minimum deposit for a mutual fund, you should clarify whether you're talking about: an investment/brokerage/mutual fund account that a normal person might invest in the stock market with, or investment banking which normally deals with millions of dollars?

Comment: What is "Lazard-Rothschild bank"? I get nearly zero results when I search for this bank.

Comment: @Flux This article efinancialcareers.com/news/2021/04/rothschild-and-lazard-working-hours indicates that they are separate banks.

Comment: Downvoted for not showing any research that "the Lazard-Rothschild bank" actually exists.

Answer (score 3):

With Schwab I believe there is no minimum.  For vanguard I believe they have a star fund that is $1000

https://clark.com/personal-finance-credit/vanguard-lowers-fund-minimums-1000/

Answer (score 1):

Most banks have no minimum, you can open an account with 1 cent if you care to.
There are probably some banks that will not bother about clients under a certain limit, but obviously, every bank in the world makes their own decision about that.